# Why does order of implementing Interfaces (with default methods) matter in Java 8?

Tags: java, interface, java-8, default-method

As we all know, multiple `interfaces` can implemented in Java. Does the order of their implementation matter? I mean, is implementing B, C is same as C, B in `Java 8`? My tests show order *does* matter - but can anyone explain the logic behind this?

```
public interface A {
    public default void display() {
        System.out.println("Display from A");
    }
}

public interface B extends A {
    public default void display() {
        System.out.println("Display from B");
    }
}

public interface C extends A {
    public void display();
}

public interface D extends B, C {

}
```

The above code works fine. If I change the order `B, C` to `C, B`, it will give an error: `The default method display() inherited from B conflicts with another method inherited from C.`

```
public interface D extends C, B {

}
```

**Edit**

I am using Eclipse(Mars). JDK `jdk1.8.0_51`. JRE `jre1.8.0_60`.

Comment: Am I missing something? If I understood correctly, you said you get an error when using one order and you don't when using a different order, which means the order makes a difference, which means you answered your own question.

Comment: Yes, I am getting the difference. I just want to know if there is any reason behind this?

Comment: You should get the same error regardless of the order (meaning, in both cases). Please check again!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31617301/what-are-the-rules-to-handle-homonym-inherited-methods

Comment: nope; compile error either way...

Comment: No, there isn't.. The error is only in one way.

Answer (score 8):

There should be an error message either way.  When I use jdk 1.8.0_31 I get the following error no matter the order of interfaces:

> The default method display() inherited from A.B conflicts with another method inherited from A.C

The solution is to either override `display()` in `D` even to just tell the compiler which super class's implementation to use:

```
public interface D extends B, C {
    default void display(){
        B.super.display();
    }
}
```

Or remake `display()` abstract

```
interface D extends B, C {
    public void display();
}
```

If you are indeed getting this error using a higher version than me, then it might be worth submitting a bug report?

Comment: D can also re-assert `display()` as abstract.

Comment: Error(it is the correct behavior) you see is same in 1.8.0_40.  Order makes no difference.

Answer (score 6):

results from **javac** (all versions 1.8.0_x):

```
error: interface D inherits abstract and default for display() from types B and C
```

resuls from **ecj** 4.4:

```
The default method display() inherited from B conflicts with another method inherited from C
```

resuls from **ecj** >= 4.4.1:

```
NO ERROR
```

Still ecj >= 4.4.1 correctly reports the error if order in `D`'s extends clause is changed.

I conclude that this is a bug in Eclipse, which got introduced in 4.4.1. I've filed [bug 477891](https://bugs.eclipse.org/477891) to follow up.

**Edit:** [bug 477891](https://bugs.eclipse.org/477891) has been fixed in Milestone 3 towards Eclipse 4.6 (GA: June 2016).